# Why is there no output in the program

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a code that displays a number in the form of the powers of the prime factors

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int chkpm(int,int);
int main()
{
    int num,i,count=-1;
    num=900;
    for(i=2;i<=num/2;i++)
    {
        if(num%i==0)
        {
               count=chkpm(num,i);
        }
        if(count>0)
        {
            cout<<i<<" ^ "<<count;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int chkpm(int num,int i)
{
    int j,flag=0; //flag will be true if i is not prime factor
    int count=0;        //to calculate power of prime factor
    for(j=1;j<=i/2;j++)  //to check for prime
    {
        if(i%j==0)  //check for divisibility
        {
            flag=1; //that means i is not prime
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)   //if factor i is prime,flag is 0
    {
        while(num%i==0) //keep dividing prime factor by num
        {          count++;  //to count power
            num=num/i;
        }
        return count;
    }
    else return -1;        //when flag=1, i.e. factor not prime
}
```

I know about the namespace and other mistakes, just need to know what is the basic correction required to make the program display the output

Comment: What have you done to try to debug it? Can't you single-step it in a debugger?

Answer (score 1):

When you check if a number is prime:

```
for(j=1;j<=i/2;j++)
```

You shouldn't start from `j=1`, because `i%1` will always be 0 and you will break after the first iteration.

Remember that a prime number is divisible by itself and 1, and only by them. So, what should the first index of `j` be according to this definition?